# Security of a simple numerical comparison

Tags: php, security

Ok I'm feeling like I'm going back not forward, can't even figure out by myself if a simple if statement is secure or not...

First of all let's say we get a variable from url GET method :

```
$my_number = $_GET['numb'];
```

Now we make this simple if statement:

```
if(($my_number >= 1) && ($my_number <= 12))
{
    put $my_number in database without escaping it
}
```

So the question would be - Can user pass this if condition with something else besides 1-12, I mean using hex numbers, commenting, doing that kind of stuff?

Comment: `put $my_number in database without escaping it` If that's a thing, you're doing it wrong (show your code which leads to an insert statement - it should never be a question as to whether user input should be escaped).

Comment: How about you try `cast string to a number` and then `check range of number` and then `insert into database using prepared statement or equivalent`.

Comment: The code is not necessary in this situation I think...let's say I just simply connect to database and then do $query = mysqli_query(my_connection,"UPDATE ... SET column = $my_number WHERE ... = ..."); but I don't really think this code is necessary

Comment: You can ensure there is nothing tricky in the number by ensuring it is an integer: $my_number = intval($_GET['numb']); You really need to make sure that the value and the format of user input is valid.

Comment: "9' something" will pass the condition because php will cast ut to int and it will be 9 for the condition clause you should always escape user input

Comment: Why bother ? Is it really that hard to escape the value or use a prepared statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate a number use `intval()`

```
$my_number = intval($_GET['numb']);
```

Nothing but a number will be allowed.
This will also insure the value will not create an error in the SQL.

I do not like `>=` or `<=`

```
if(($my_number >= 1) && ($my_number <= 12))
```

Change to:

```
if(($my_number > 0) && ($my_number < 13))
```

Comment: intval() is good.  We tend to use filter_var($my_number, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT).  This will return FALSE if $my_number is not a number whereas intval() will return zero - which is a number and that can be a problem when using something like " >= 0" as all strings will match.

Comment: The intval() types the value to integer.  If anything other than a numeric value is passed, or empty, it will convert to a zero.  In this case a zero value is filtered out with `if($my_number > 0`. Then in the SQL the value cannot be blank and will not create an error if the variable is not put in single quotes.  In this case wouldn't you use `filter_input()` rather than `var_filter()`?

Comment: two things. I didn't explain myself very well... I fully agree that intval() is awesome in that it only returns numbers.  Of late, zeros, FALSE, empties, etc. have been giving me trouble - so having a non-number if the value of $my_number is not number usually proves helpful (just for me and my programming style).
Historically, some of the platforms I have deployed to have had a problem with filter_input().  NO idea why, but it has happened enough for me to just stop using it.
I don't disagree with you, @Misunderstood, I was just offering a (poorly defined) different approach!

Comment: zero, false,null are problematic especially when a function can return either zero or false like `strpos()`.  Then you use `if $pos !==  false`.  But the beauty of `intval()` is, there is no ambiguity of the type, it will never return false or null.  The main reason I would use `intval()` over `filter_var()`, it is a simple and more efficient method.

Answer (score -2):

Your code is not fully secured. User can pass this if condition with something else besides 1-12.
You can test that with this simple code:

```
<?php

$my_number = $_GET['numb'];

if(is_numeric($my_number)){
if(($my_number >= 1) && ($my_number <= 12))
{
echo'User Can Pass';
}else{
echo'User Can Not Pass';
}
}else{
echo'User Can Not Pass';
}    
?>
```

Now browse your site like `http://example.com/?numb=8` or `http://example.com/?numb=15` or `http://example.com/?numb=7 Samurai`

I think now you can find your answer. Thanks.

Comment: `$my_number = '0x0A';` or `$my_number = '7 Samurai';` May not always be what you want or expect;

Comment: I think `0x0A` is not a number. `$_GET['numb']` should be a number.

Comment: Try substituting those values I quoted and see whether they pass or fail according to your code, then you might understand why you've been downvoted; or try `$my_number = "1' or 68 = '66; DROP ALL TABLES; --"`

Comment: What if $mynumber evaluates to 7{quote};drop table users; -- that is between 1 and 12. Note: I cannot put a ' in {quote}. It throws an error when I submit the comment.

Comment: Sorry. I have updated my code. Thank you @Mark Baker